# как сделать стрелку при наведении на кнопку

Tags: html5

не понимаю как сделать такую вот стрелочку при наведении (либо просто ее сделать и рядом прикрепить)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте через `::before` и `::after`

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом создаётся каретка стрелочки.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a.has-children {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
a.has-children:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
a.has-children:hover:after {
  border-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="has-children" href="#">Материалы</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Документы</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Контакты</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```